# How to know if MKMapView is allowed to use current location?

Tags: objective-c, location, mkmapview, cllocationmanager, showuserlocation

I am showing the user location on a mapView with:

`self.mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;`

The user gets prompted the AlertView where he can choose whether to allow to use the current location or not.
If he presses yes everything is ok and I do not worry about it.

But if he presses NO I would like to zoom to a specific region.

So how do I know whether the MKMapView is allowed to use the current location?

I found the solution where I would create my own CLLocationManager and its delegate to see if it returns an denied error.
But this does not quite feel right, why introduce a new CLLocationManger if I do not need it.

Isn't there an other way?

Comment: Have you checked the `CLLocationManager Class Reference`? There're several lines of text telling that you should use `authorizationStatus` method of CLLocationManager class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a delegate. Just use the CLLocationManager class method `authorizationStatus`:

```
if ([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) {
    // allowed
} else {
    // not allowed
}
```

The possible values are:

```
typedef enum {
   kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined = 0,
   kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted,
   kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied,
   kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized
} CLAuthorizationStatus;
```

Comment: exactly what I needed! Thank you! I was so fixed on that delegate thing I did not even think about this solution!.